# Characterise the set of solutions of a nonlinear system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, groebner-basis

Consider system of $8$ equations
$$
\alpha^j(1-\alpha)^ip+(1-\alpha)^j \alpha^i (1-p)=q_{j,i} \hspace{1cm} \forall j\in \{0,1,...,7\}, i\in \{0,1,...,7\} \text{ s.t. } i+j=7
$$
where:

- $\{\alpha,p\}$ are the unknowns
- $q_{j,i}$ is known and in $[0,1]$ $\forall j\in \{0,1,...,7\}, i\in \{0,1,...,7\} \text{ s.t. } i+j=7$
- $\alpha\in (\frac{1}{2},1]$, $p\in [0,1]$

Suppose that all the conditions required for the system to have at least one solution wrto $\alpha,p$ are satisfied. Could you help to characterise the set of solutions of the system? Is it singleton?

---

The answer below is very helpful.
However, I've decided to start a bounty because I'm looking for more details on the Grobner basis method (I'm a beginner): why do I need it here? In rough and simple words, what does it consist of? How do we practically implement it for my specific case? What does it give us?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $8$ equations in only $2$ unknowns, so having solutions is rather special.

Subtracting the equation for $j=3,i=4$ from the equation for $j=4$,$i=3$ you get $$\alpha^3 (1-\alpha)^3 (2 \alpha - 1) (2 p-1) = 0$$
Now it's easy to check that neither $\alpha = 0$ nor $\alpha = 1$ will work, while if $p = 1/2$ you get (after eliminating $q$) a set of polynomials in $\alpha$ whose greatest common divisor is $2\alpha - 1$.  Thus the only way to have a solution is $\alpha = 1/2$.  With $\alpha = 1/2$, you must have $q = 1/128$, and $p$ is arbitrary.

But you don't seem to allow $\alpha =1/2$, in which case you are out of luck: there are no other solutions.

EDIT: Replacing $q$ by $q_{j,i}$ (let me call it $q_j$, since $i+j=7$) makes a big difference.  Obviously any $p$ and $\alpha$ are possible: just substitute in the equations to find the corresponding values of $q_{j}$.  There are equations in the $q_j$ that need to be satisfied: using a Groebner basis in Maple, I find
$$ {q_{{5}}}^{6}+7\,{q_{{5}}}^{5}q_{{6}}+5\,{q_{{5}}}^{5}q_{{7}}+16\,{q_{
{5}}}^{4}{q_{{6}}}^{2}+28\,{q_{{5}}}^{4}q_{{6}}q_{{7}}+10\,{q_{{5}}}^{
4}{q_{{7}}}^{2}+7\,{q_{{5}}}^{3}{q_{{6}}}^{3}+47\,{q_{{5}}}^{3}q_{{7}}
{q_{{6}}}^{2}+42\,{q_{{5}}}^{3}q_{{6}}{q_{{7}}}^{2}+10\,{q_{{5}}}^{3}{
q_{{7}}}^{3}-22\,{q_{{5}}}^{2}{q_{{6}}}^{4}+7\,{q_{{5}}}^{2}{q_{{6}}}^
{3}q_{{7}}+45\,{q_{{5}}}^{2}{q_{{7}}}^{2}{q_{{6}}}^{2}+28\,{q_{{5}}}^{
2}q_{{6}}{q_{{7}}}^{3}+5\,{q_{{5}}}^{2}{q_{{7}}}^{4}-28\,q_{{5}}{q_{{6
}}}^{5}-40\,q_{{5}}{q_{{6}}}^{4}q_{{7}}-7\,q_{{5}}{q_{{6}}}^{3}{q_{{7}
}}^{2}+13\,q_{{5}}{q_{{7}}}^{3}{q_{{6}}}^{2}+7\,q_{{5}}q_{{6}}{q_{{7}}
}^{4}+q_{{5}}{q_{{7}}}^{5}-8\,{q_{{6}}}^{6}-20\,{q_{{6}}}^{5}q_{{7}}-
18\,{q_{{6}}}^{4}{q_{{7}}}^{2}-7\,{q_{{6}}}^{3}{q_{{7}}}^{3}-{q_{{6}}}
^{2}{q_{{7}}}^{4}-{q_{{6}}}^{5}=0
$$
which describes a certain surface in $q_5, q_6, q_7$ space.
$q_4$, $q_3$, $q_2$, $q_1$, $q_0$ are then determined by the values of $q_5, q_6, q_7$.  The equation for $\alpha$ is a quadratic:
$$\alpha^2-\alpha+q_1+5 q_2+10 q_3+10 q_4+5 q_5+q_6=0$$
so there may be two values of $\alpha$.  However, since $\alpha^2 - \alpha$ is strictly increasing for $\alpha \ge 1/2$, only one
can be $\ge 1/2$.  And finally, the equation for $p$ is linear in $p$, of the form
$$ (448 q_6-320 q_7-1) p + f(\alpha, q_1, \ldots, q_7)=0$$
so at least if $448 q_6 - 320 q_7 \ne 1$, $p$ is uniquely determined.

EDIT: Explicitly, this last equation is
$$  \left( 448\,q_{{6}}-320\,q_{{7}}-1 \right) p+1+15616\,\alpha\,q_{{5}}
q_{{6}}+32768\,\alpha\,q_{{5}}q_{{7}}+q_{{1}}+8\,q_{{2}}+29\,q_{{3}}+
64\,q_{{4}}+99\,q_{{5}}-136\,q_{{6}}+319\,q_{{7}}-\alpha-58\,\alpha\,q
_{{3}}-128\,\alpha\,q_{{4}}-13184\,q_{{4}}q_{{5}}-1664\,q_{{3}}q_{{4}}
-16\,\alpha\,q_{{2}}-2\,\alpha\,q_{{1}}-256\,q_{{2}}q_{{7}}-2048\,q_{{
3}}q_{{7}}-7424\,q_{{4}}q_{{7}}-7808\,q_{{5}}q_{{6}}-16384\,q_{{5}}q_{
{7}}-2432\,q_{{6}}q_{{7}}-15872\,{q_{{5}}}^{2}-6272\,{q_{{4}}}^{2}-192
\,{q_{{3}}}^{2}+26368\,\alpha\,q_{{4}}q_{{5}}+3328\,\alpha\,q_{{3}}q_{
{4}}+12544\,\alpha\,{q_{{4}}}^{2}+512\,\alpha\,q_{{2}}q_{{7}}+4096\,
\alpha\,q_{{3}}q_{{7}}+14848\,\alpha\,q_{{4}}q_{{7}}+4864\,\alpha\,q_{
{6}}q_{{7}}+31744\,\alpha\,{q_{{5}}}^{2}+384\,\alpha\,{q_{{3}}}^{2}-
318\,\alpha\,q_{{7}}-16640\,\alpha\,{q_{{6}}}^{2}+640\,\alpha\,{q_{{7}
}}^{2}-198\,\alpha\,q_{{5}}-176\,\alpha\,q_{{6}}+8320\,{q_{{6}}}^{2}-
320\,{q_{{7}}}^{2}
=0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very useful. I actually realised that there was a typo in my question: I want to allow $q$ to vary across $\{j,i\}$. I have edited my question by adding the subscripts $j,i$ to $q$. Do your arguments still apply? Many thanks and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Many thanks. May I ask you: 1) how did you get the quadratic equation for $\alpha$? 2) And the linear equation for $p$? 3) Lastly, what does it mean "at least if" in the last line? Does it mean that there may be other necessary conditions somewhere?

Comment: As I wrote, I used Maple to find a Groebner basis.  "At least if" because if the coefficient of $p$ is $0$, this equation doesn't determine $p$.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. May I ask you whether the function $f$ at the end of your answer should also depend on $q_0$? Also, if the function $f $is equalised to zero, then $p$ is zero? I'm concern about that result.

Comment: It does not depend on $q_0$, only $\alpha$ and $q_1$ to $q_7$.  I'll add it to the answer (it's too big for a comment).

Comment: Actually you can determine $p$ from the first of your equations if $\alpha \ne 1/2$ and is real.  On the other hand, if $\alpha = 1/2$, $p$ can be anything.